# Guidance on singleton tags in the "Suggested Edits" queue

Tags: discussion

I've rejected several edits that I believe are part of a tag creation process because the tag itself seemed unnecessary (created just for the question being asked).  [Here is the most recent example](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32028).

It occurs to me now that maybe I'm being wrongheaded about this.  The edit itself is a valid explanation for the tag being suggested.  Should I restrain my response to that, or should the question "does this tag add to the site" contribute to my response?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you were right in this case, and probably others, but I would go a step further and also remove the tag (which is a singleton in this case) from the question it was created on so that the tag will be auto-removed by the system.

Comment: is [the guidance for tags in help](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) incorrect?  "Even if you have sufficient reputation, you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site."  What I've understood by osmosis, and am reading echoed here, is that the preference is to have tags group together questions and not just get created for novel topics (maybe that works better on StackOverflow when new programming languages are introduced?)

Comment: Yeah, I think that language works best for sites like Stack Overflow where the topics are really concrete. But also sometimes a tag is just not a well conceived topic. "Activate" is especially bad. That's not really a cohesive topic in this context.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that these one-off tags should be removed from the system.

Answer (score 3):

#### tl;dr: I have a strong bias against that and I think that's fine

Though I've created many tags on this site and others, to my best recollection I haven't ever created a singleton. (I may write a main meta post about "how to get my tag creation report card" and/or "which users create singletons" though a clear definition of singleton would then be necessary. Is it one now vs was it at the time for example.

For sites like Space SE with a mature portfolio of tags, I think there can be an [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_operating_procedure) for tag creation. It would start with a proposal in a meta question, including a short justification and list of several proposed questions where it would be added, and a short discussion of any similar tags and why there is little enough overlap and sufficient usefulness to show the tag is a good idea.

I often follow this process. I can't say I've always done it but I've done it many times. If I follow through and create the tag I make sure to add it to all the question for which I felt it was helpful in the first place.

Primarily, I think the utility of tags is future searching, but I think "how are tags actually being used in 2022 and beyond?" would also be worth exploring in meta in some way, first to read what's been written, then to see if as technology and search engines evolve, how tags are used is actually changing from their original perceived utility.

When I review questions (new posts or edits) I also pay some attention to tags and if they are unfamiliar I check to see if they are used. If they are newly created singletons I have a strong bias against this.

To that end, I think something in the main meta roughly like "Should newly created singleton tags have a visual indicator, or a filter on the tag page, or have a trial period or expiration date if they don't get used again?"

Of course it can't be asked like that, I guess the title would be "How to better manage singleton tags?"

Comment: I admit I don't think about tags very much.  The textual content of the post tends to do a fine job stitching relating them to each other all on its own.  The only really nice feature (which I also don't use) of the tag seems to be following it.  If I could get enough people talking about RPOP I would totally follow that tag.

Comment: @ErinAnne should I ask where the Newman Line got its name?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I admit I haven't heard of that / gotten the joke

Comment: @ErinAnne it was probably only in the shuttle version

Comment: @OrganicMarble I did a little digging and found a "thanks" dedication to a Jim Newman that worked in CB, where RPOP's predecessor program PLBAY came from.  If you can find a publicly available resource displaying the Newman line I might be able to tell you more (is it the moving-numbers relative motion predictors?) but I'd probably have to ask the folks currently working in EG6 for more

Comment: @ErinAnne You got it. Jim Newman was an astronaut who came out of Training Division, he was an instructor and Sim Sup. He was on the first ISS shuttle mission, STS-88, among others. There's a reference to the Newman Line in the Rndz Crew Training Handbook, at least the shuttle version, on page 2.5-7